# Block keyboard on debian

Tags: debian, kiosk

I would like to block the keyboard for a kiosk-based application implemented on Linux. The keyboard could be blocked with "nohup cat /dev/tty0" on some Linux distributions, but it's not working on Debian. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I rewrote your question with better English. I think it makes more sense now, but please check and make sure I didn't actually break it :) Also you don't have to include greetings or thanks in your question. You do that by voting and participating here.

Comment: I think `cat /dev/tty0` only worked back when input devices could only be opened by one program at a time. I'd go for either disabling the keyboard through `xorg.conf`, or unbinding every key with xmodmap or xkb. It may take more than that to prevent the user from changing the mapping table or plugging in a keyboard and triggering an automatic driver load.

Comment: Does the kiosk-mode run under Xorg? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly set following option to disable hotplugging in xorg.conf or xorg.conf.d/misc.conf:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DisableModInDev" "True"
EndSection
```

Then disable all keyboards:

```
Section "InputClass"
    MatchIsKeyboard       "True"
    Option "Ignore"       "True"
EndSection
```

Comment: Also make sure that the "Magic SysRQ keys" option in the kernel config is set to OFF -- in debian stock kernels it defaults to 'on' because it's such an incredibly handy emergency measure, but it's something you most likely don't want kiosk users to have access to...